# Create a file with the grep search in a folder where the search is done

Tags: bash, grep

I want to create a file with the output of a grep search but in a folder included in the search. If I do:

```
grep -rnw . -e "text" > test/files.txt
```

It never ends because it always add one more files.txt. How can I do it after it finishes?

```
grep -rnw . -e "text" >| test/files.txt
```

This gives the same output than the previous one.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parent directory:

```
grep -rnw . -e "text" > ../files.txt && mv ../files.txt test/files.txt
```

This, however, relies on relative path which may fail in some contexts. Use static independent path (for example, `/tmp`) to avoid that.

Comment: Your first answer worked fine:  `grep -rnw . -e "text" > test/files.tmp && mv test/files.tmp test/files.txt`. I didn't think about the temporal files.

Comment: @Llopis it will fail if you need to parse all files (i.e. without some mask). That's why I've updated

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
cat <<< "$(grep -rnw . -e "text")" > test/files.txt
```